# Stability of palatalized consonants

Tags: historical-linguistics, palatalization, diachronic

Some palatalized consonants seem to have a greater tendency to "absorb" their palatalization (in various ways) than others.

For example, in standard Japanese, the former palatalized alveolars *tj*, *dj*, *zj* and *sj* have become [tʃ], [dʒ] and [ʃ]:

- *de**sh**ō* ("Isn't it?", etc.) < *de**s**(u) **y**ō*
- ***j***ō ("above", etc.) < ****zy**au*
- ***j**a* ("so", "then", etc.) < ****dy**a* < *dewa*
- ***ch***ō ("morning", etc.) < ****ty**(e)u* < *teu*

However, Japanese has retained most other palatalized sounds as such: velar stops (***Ky***ōtō, **Gy**ōza), back-fricatives (***hy***aku "100"), labial stops (*rop**py**aku* "600") and resonants (***ry***ōri "cooking", *gyu**ny**u* "milk", etc.).

In Norwegian and Swedish, both the palatalized alveolars and velars have changed into something else:

- *sj* (as in ***sj***ø / **sj**ö "sea") > [ʃ] / [ɧ]
- *tj* (as in ***tj***ære / **tj**ära "tar") > [ç] / [ɕ]
- *dj* (as in Sw. ***dj***ur "animal") > [j]
- *kj* (***kj***øtt / ***k***ött "flesh") > [ç] / [ɕ]
- *skj* (***skj***orte / ***skj***orta "shirt") > [ʃ] / [ɧ]
- *gj* (as in ***gj***orde "did") > [j]

Other palatalized sounds in these languages seem mostly to remain as such: ***bj***örn / **bj**ørn "bear", ***fj***äll / **fj**ell "mountain", ***mj***öl / **mj**øl "flour", Swedish ***nj***ure "kidney", etc.

Are cases like these the norm, cross-linguistically speaking? I.e., are palatalized alveolar obstruents ([tj]/[dj]/[sj]/etc.) generally more diachronically "unstable" than palatalized velar stops, which in turn are less stable than most/all other palatalized consonants?

Thanks for any info

Comment: There might be a clear question herein, but it's impossible to figure out what you mean by "like these". What do these cases contrast with? Are you asking about particular places of articulation? Are you asking about the distinction between "phonetically palatalized" i.e. Cʲ outputs versus alveopalatals? Do you interpret all Cj onsets as "palatalized"? Is the question about two-segment sequences (Cj) versus single segment sequences (Cʲ)? Is this about synchronic analysis versus diachronic change? (Norwegian [çøtt] is surely from /çøtt/ though diachronically it is from something with [kj].

Comment: For the purposes of this question, yes, I am interpreting the sequence of [consonant] + [j] as a "palatalized consonant". I am not making a distinction here between [Cʲ] and [Cj]. And this question is about sound change, not synchronic analysis. Can you please reread the final two sentences of my post above and let me know if the question is still unclear?